# factory-boy create a list of SubFactory for a Factory

Tags: django, factory, factory-boy

I am using django 1.6 and factory-boy.

```
class UserFactory(factory.Factory):
   class Meta:
      model = models.User

   username = factory.Sequence(lambda n: 'user%d' % n)
```

Here `username` is a simple `CharField` in model. So that each time I am calling `UserFactory()` I am saving and getting unique user named object.

In factory-boy I can use `factory.SubFactory(SomeFactory)`.

How I can generate list of `SomeFactory` in `ParentOfSomeFactory` ?

So that, if I call `ParentOfSomeFactory()` I will create list of SomeFactory as well as ParentOfSomeFactory database

Comment: Just to make sure, even if you create a list of sub factories, the field type is still non-list type field, how you wanted to handle it? in your example, what would you do if the `lambda` would return list?

Comment: what would you do if the lambda would return list?

So that if I call ParentOfSomeFactory() It will automatically create and save a list of SomeFactory model at database. I dont want to create it manually.

Answer (score 36):

Use [factory.List](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#dict-and-list):

```
class ParentOfUsers(factory.Factory):
    users = factory.List([
        factory.SubFactory(UserFactory) for _ in range(5)
    ])
```

Answer (score 5):

You could provide a list with [factory.Iterator](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#factory.Iterator)

```
import itertools
import factory

# cycle through the same 5 users
users = itertools.cycle(
    (UserFactory() for _ in range(5))
)

class ParentFactory(factory.Factory):
    user = factory.Iterator(users)
```